# Can I revoke the project's license after I translate its code?

Tags: licensing, open-source, mit-license

I am planning on converting an old project originally from Objective-C to Swift.

The project is currently under the MIT License, and any distributions of it must maintain the same MIT License. However, as far as I know, this only applies if the current code is used, but after I convert it to Swift, the whole syntax would change...Does that mean that I'm free on implementing any other license?

Comment: Honestly, the current answers have been very useful to help me to understand the open source licensing. I'm sorry but I won't be able to choose one correct answer since they are all equally important to me.

Answer (score 2):

The MIT license is a liberal license that basically says that you can do anything with the code that you want to, including making it closed source, translating it to another language, and so forth.

> **The MIT License (MIT)**
>   `Copyright (c) <year> <copyright holders>`
>
> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

Essentially, the only thing you can't do is alter the licensing terms for code that users have already obtained under a particular license, including MIT.  You must also preserve the copyright and permission notice for substantial portions of the original code that are used verbatim.  Note that users are still free to obtain the original code from its original source.

Answer (score 2):

When converting a program from one source language to another source language, you create a [derivative work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_work).  It's the same principle than a translation into a foreign language of a book.

Law is heavily dependent on your jurisdiction.  But the general principle is:

- you need the authorisation of the copyright holder to create a derivative work. Fortunately, the [MIT license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License) grants you this right : it allows you "*to deal in the software without restriction*", provided that you comply with the license conditions, i.e. copyright notice and permission in all copies.
- if this conversion is a substantial work and bears your own personality (i.e. it's not just a semi-automated conversion, but a real intellectual effort of yours), I think you'd own yourself a [copyright on the derivative work](http://www.copyright.gov/circs/circ14.pdf) (i.e. on your Swift version, not on the original one).  So you should be allowed to add to the original copyright notice, a copyright notice restricted to the converted version.
- I think that you have to license your converted Swift version under MIT license, because the acceptance of the MIT terms is a condition to be allowed to do the derivative work.  However this MIT license would only be mandatory for the converted version, and not for additional work unrelated to the original software (e.g. added functions, or software that would embed the converted code).

***Disclaimer:*** this is a personal opinion based on my own experience and knowledge and shall in no way be considered as legal advice.  For legal advice you should consult a qualified lawyer or legal expert